# Show that $f\colon \Bbb R_+ →\Bbb R$, $x\mapsto x \ln(x) − x$ is convex.

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

I tried the second derivative test but it doesn't seem right, I feel like I am missing something. Any suggestions on a new route to try?

Comment: Could you elaborate on your work? Second derivative is not a bad choice...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unclear where you could fail: We have $f'(x)=\ln x $, $f''(x)=\frac1x$, so $f''(x)>0$ for all $x$.

Comment: *for all $x>0  $

Comment: That is what I did, but for some reason I am just not convinced that that solution completely shows the convexity of the function. Maybe I am just overthinking it, thanks for your response!

Comment: @Wojowu which is the same as "for all $x$ in the domain of $f$ and mentioning that $x$ is in the domain of $f$ should be unnecessary